# Updating two databases on different server using SSIS

Tags: database, ssis

I have a database A and database B(on different servers), both databases contains emp table, I want to update this emp table on both databases using single dtsx file using SSIS. Source: flat file, Destination: emp tble

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the Mulitcast component. It allows for multiple downstream components to access the same data (without physically copying the data around in memory)

## Control Flow

```
           Execute SQL Task (Truncate S1.A.dbo.emp)
                  |
           Execute SQL Task (Truncate S2.B.dbo.emp)
                  |
            Data Flow Task
```

### DataFlow Task

```
           Flat File Source
                  |
              Multicast
                  |
OLE DB Dest S1.A     OLE DB Dest S2.B
```